# How can I lauch a GNU screen from jailshell (no pty)

Tags: gnu-screen, bsd

I have my personal stuff hosted with a company that uses cpanel. It seems that a "feature" of cpanel is that the hosting company can use their "jailshell" when granting (terminal, not goofy AJAX faked) SSH access. Unfortunately you do not have access to /dev/pty and when trying to run screen you get the error:

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

I have also tried "ssh -t example.com screen" but get the same result.

Has anyone every gotten screen to work under jailshell, or on a host where you do not have access to /dev/pty?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to work around a restriction intentionally set up by a service of which you are a user.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it concerns the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicely ask your host to enable /bin/bash  It's literally a one click "upgrade" in WHM that takes 10 seconds to enable.  If they won't do it, then you are stuck as everyone else has said.

Comment: I did ask for access to bash and was told that it would give me root access and they, of course, can't do that on a shared server. I know that is a load of crap because my day job is as a  MySQL DBA, Linux System Administrator, and Manager of a team of Linux System Administrators. I didn't argue because I know that arguing with someone who is willing to lie to you and insult your intelligence... is a fruitless demonstration of your lack of intelligence. What I didn't know is that WHM controls it. I will try to social engineer my way into it. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: @jemmille, I had root access but not WHM acceess (it's my client's VPS server). Can I do this from root account instead? Is changing the user shell into /bin/bash is enough?

Answer (score 2):

You need pseudo tty's for screen to work, there's no way around that. Unless you can convince your hosting company to bind mount `/dev` in to your chroot jail there's not really much else you can hope to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't GNU Screen needs a working pty to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Screen needs a proper tty to work. It needs an environment as good as when you would login using telnet/ssh/console (ie. a working terminal).

- Ram

Comment: No offense, but I hope there is something you guys are overlooking. I'm going to leave this open a little longer.  

What I have is a working terminal (ssh connection), but I have a limited (possibly chrooted) shell.

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck.  Screen needs a tty to work.